# Antenna model by chatGPT AI - correct or not?

Tags: antenna, transmission-line, modeling

I asked chatGPT about a basic simplified model of an antenna according to my conception of it (pasted is the most relevant part of two separate answers).

[image]

[image]

It would look like this:

[image]

ChatGPT AI confirmed it, but I have some doubts. Speaking by and large, on the whole, is that a reasonable model for an antenna and its interface with free space? (if it's 70% alright that's fine with me).

Based on previous discussion, chatGPT told me that #3 as a resistor is only correct if the length of the antenna is at a certain ratio to the signal wavelength. Otherwise #3 would be a complex reactance (and "steal" more power). The same is implied in this answer. But the main point is not to calculate the reactance #3, but whether the series of components #1 through #4 is the right model (even if the components might have somewhat different values).

#3 is not the last load resistor which you are free to choose, but an antenna property which would be complex except at the right frequency.

See schematic to the correct order of #1 through #4 (chat knew it because of previous context in earlier queries - we went over this a number of times).

Comment: oh no chatGPT will soon be able to replace this site :) It's also very good at composing fictional stories based on a prompt you give. Very creative fictional stories.

Comment: This is an excellent illustration of why it won't: chatgpt at no stage has an understanding of an antenna. It can just create sentences that would have a high likelihood of being right in a given context. And agreeing with you looks quite right. But isn't.

Comment: Sometimes it disagreed with me conclusively. It doesn't always agree, but it's definitely always polite.

Comment: By the way, answers generated by chatgpt are already against the rules to post here. Not sure whether questioning an answer of chatgpt is much better, but I think your question as is doesn't even need chatgpt. You're just asking us whether you understood a technical concept correctly.

Comment: yes that's correct, but it helps that I've got support behind my hypothesis. It may be wrong though, so we have to see..

Comment: It does not help. It misleads. It gives a false sense of understanding! It actually hurts.

Comment: What's the point if this question regarding this site? Is there any validity in it?

Comment: @Andyaka I didn't know that chatGPT is a thorny subject. I'll take responsibility on myself for everything chatGPT said. Let's say it came entirely from me. I wouldn't have mentioned it if I knew that 90% of the energy would go into commenting on chatpgt and 10% on helping with an answer.

Comment: I've never heard of that site but, your question seems to be focussed on it and that seems irrelevant to this site. Stick to asking valid EE questions, focus on that. You mention the site's name 9 times in your question/comments so, maybe you could have expected a fairly healthy response on that subject.

Comment: ChatGPT is a thorny subject because people have been using it to post bogus answers.  The "answers" look plausible because the grammar and structure are at least half way decent and they are written so as to appear authorative.  It takes someone who knows the subject to review the answers and expose the BS - this takes time from writing real answers.

Comment: Fine, but any fair reading of the question [ ] shows that I was interested in model. chatAI was mentioned almost as a by the way. 90% of the energy was spent commenting on chatAI, which is a topic they apparently really enjoy talking about, despite what they say, & very little help with the model. [Edited by a moderator to comply with the Code of Conduct.]

Comment: Your question falls in the same category.  Instead of asking for help from experts in understanding a subject, you ask a chatbot.  That thing appears to confirm your assumptions, but then you mistrust it enough to ask experts after all.  Cut out the middle man (the chatbot) and ask the experts first.  They can deal with your questions better if they don't have to work against the BS produced by the chatbot.

Comment: Your question is mostly a reference to ChatGPT, with the actual question being an aside. The bulk of your text is about ChatGPT and its response.

Comment: If I asked what is the model of an antenna point blank, I would have gotten a book of info. Starting with a model, even if wrong, in my view is helpful. All the info is contained in the schematic. [ ] [Edited by a moderator to comply with the Code of Conduct.]

Comment: Starting with an explanation of your understanding is fine.  Muddying the waters with a long exposition on what ChatGPT thinks of your views does not help.  Reduce your question to "Here's my understanding, have I got it right" and that'd be fine.  Add in a long list of "ChatGPT says this and that and the other about my understanding" and you've got a muddled mess that bugs people.  It's like saying you laid tarot cards to see if  your understanding is correct and the cards delivered an ambiguous answer so now you ask an expert.

Comment: You've got it reversed on one point - I didn't have a view before chat suggested one. I started point blank. Chat suggested a model. That's the only model I've got. [ ] [Edited by a moderator to comply with the Code of Conduct.]

Comment: *is that a reasonable model for an antenna and its interface with free space?* <-- no it isn't (if you want my direct answer). Additionally, there's nothing in your "conversation" with the AI thing that appears to justify that electrical model as far as I can see (and understand). The problem with questions that assert things that are basically wrong is that they are just not worth the effort answering most of the time. I think the most appropriate model is of a transmission line that graduates linearly from one impedance to another and, that's a tricky model to make accurately.

Comment: @ee_student So what would you call the output of conversational bot then? It is trained to be chatty, it is not trained to be an antenna expert. It might sound convincing, but it won't know how antennas work and can't answer questions about them. It's just a sophisticated random generator.

Comment: [I've posted a question in Meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9793/should-questions-about-chatgpt-responses-be-closed) about ChatGPT driven questions.

Comment: Andy, I'll say about the part about asking about things that are wrong: that's the way to learn. Other than the gradual thing, is there a way to approximately model with TL and impedance? It seemed a simple model. Even when googling I saw a picture of a dipole antenna, it had a TL line on each branch and a resistor following it? And the thing that triggers everyone said it's correct.

Comment: A t-line has the same impedance at one end as the other. This is not true when using a t-line to model an antenna. As I said in my last comment, you need a t-line that graduates from one impedance to another and, that's a whole different ball-park to a simple t-line used in simulators. And no, if you assert things that are wrong (as opposed to something like "I was told this") then it makes it difficult to answer. So, what the AI thing said and, what you said in your 1st comment was: *oh no chatGPT will soon be able to replace this site* and that set the scene. The added spice made a bad taste

Comment: Thanks for answer (no irony). It was obviously a joke but whatever. Pls read the question, "I was told this" is very nearly what I said, and then I've added that I have some doubt. I don't want to make a big deal, like you say the wrong word and I jump at you (plural yous), but I'd say the dynamic on this thread was rather uncommon, and I still don't see the big deal of the whole chat thing. If it was wrong if it was nice model to start from.

Comment: @All - As some of you probably expected, this Q has come to the attention of mods, so as exception handlers, we've got to get involved. || While raising issues about a question *politely & constructively* is allowed in comments (up to a line), it's a shame that this has gone over the line into *personal* criticism, which is [*not allowed*](/help/conduct). Now we will have to go & delete / edit things :( (Meta statements in Q&A are also not allowed and will be removed.) Even if you disagree with what someone else says, *do not make it personal* or even *sound* personal.

Comment: (continued) Although the mods have been discussing the issues of AI-generated answers (Meta post to follow, in due course) I hadn't predicted AI-generated content in *questions*. Fundamentally, I agree with the main point made by some site members: It is so easy for AI to generate questions which take **disproportionate** time & effort for others to unravel and point out the flaws, that such questions are likely to end up wasting the time of the site members who kindly volunteer to write to answers here.

Comment: (continued)  This means we'll have to have a policy on Q with AI-generated content, as well as A (thanks for the Meta question on that, although the future policy is already almost certain).

Comment: (continued) This question is so derailed (and has become more about ChatGPT etc.) that it's not salvageable. To prevent any further off-topic and/or personal comments it has been locked, at least for the moment, as experience shows that just asking people to stop isn't enough (until we start suspending people for disrupting the site by ignoring those requests, and we don't want to suspend people, if that can be avoided). It has been a good example (unfortunately) of the problems that questions with AI-generated content can cause.

Comment: (continued)  Discuss Q with AI-generated content in Meta (*politely*) and/or ask a Q about an antenna model, with references & links to *human-written* sources which are unclear and which you need help understanding. Do not use or refer to AI-generated responses in a question (or answer) as explained above.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about a response from ChatGPT.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss antenna models, please see the question where I cite a publish research, showing that the model above is quite accurate in terms of its topology:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/649545/evaluating-antenna-models-as-presented-in-a-recent-research-paper

Comment: Let make a concluding remark that maybe it was in justice to close the question. I don't see exactly why, but let's allow that. On the other hand, both the answer and the few of the comments were largely wrong. Notice that in the research paper, they don't have a model only for the resonant frequency. They have a single model for all frequencies, and as the graph shows, in some frequencies there are reflections (S22). Thus saying that a model has to have a "graduated" or "piece" TL to be accurate is false. Saying that a complex impedance is used for the feed instead of a 50 TL is false.

Comment: Also incorrect is saying that if there are reflections, the model is wrong. The antenna is what it is, and in some frequencies it would indeed reflect, just as the graph in the research paper shows (S22). At the most you can say that the antenna is not resonant at a particular chosen frequency. But that's not the same as saying that you need a "piece" or "graduated" TL (to freespace), and it's not the same as saying that a feedline in the form of a 50 ohm TL is not what models typically use. Thus upvoting the answer\comments is largely incorrect (even as closing the question may be in justice)

Answer (score 3):

No, your mental model of an antenna is flawed.

If you want to model an antenna as transmission line, it would have to be a piece transmission line that can transform the wave impedance of your system - more or less well - to that of free space.

But because you're using the same impedance as your feed/system, that can't happen.

Two things:

1. No reason to model an antenna as transmission line. A complex loss impedance that represents the feed point impedance of the antenna would be easier to understand - you'd just be recreating that measurable impedance by means of using a unmatched length of transmission line, anyways.
2. ChatGPT has positively no idea about anything in this world. It is trained to give answers that will look reasonable in a given context, based on the petabytes of context it has seen on the internet. So don't base your understanding on it - you'll look like someone who has heard all the right words, but sitting in an exam, couldn't solve the easiest problem the professor could come up with, because you have no notion of the model, just conversational abilities.

And because I was involved in the design, grading and conduction of enough exams in an EE field: I'm not fond of arguing through "you will have a hard time in an exam", because I don't believe in exams being important; they're just or very crude way of justifying giving people a title. If we could do without, we should.

You should definitely learn how to discuss topics, but chatGPT is actively training you to sound smart on a topic, without having the mental model of the thing you talk about. This is, in my humble opinion, not helping anyone build any skills of any particular field. All the knowledge ChatGPT seems to have is really just a big word-dice that it weighs such that words out rolls are most likely the same words a person would say given a prompt. That sadly doesn't mean it understands the words out what has been asked. It's great for doing "hello, IT. Have you tried turning it off and on again?"-style support.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that you mentioned two things:
1. Instead of TL line use complex impedance.
2. You can keep TL line, if it recreates that complex impedance, but it's more complex.
As to #2, even if you don't need a TL line, and it just makes it more complex, is it more or less accurate what chat suggested:
A. TL line of 75 ohm for an antenna
B. impedance following the line depending on the length of the antenna
C. free space as another TL
Drawback: looking out from the TL into space - always reflection.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying in the second half of your comment. There's no more or less accurate in "exact". Again, conversational skills, not an understanding of the math shows through.

Comment: you understood that I just mean approximate.

Comment: No, I don't understand, sorry. That makes little sense.

Comment: Maybe there's was a real miscommunication, so I guess I'll try again: is the way chatgpt suggested simply more complicated or wrong even as a first approximation. If somebody says to me you can model active transistor's base with 0.6 V, it's not accurate, but it's an approximation..

Comment: On second read, I'd say it's inaccurate, as the model includes the feed line as part of the antenna. But honestly, not keen on discussing whether that is a sensible interpretation of the word antenna for a chat ai - it is so much cheaper for the chat ai to just make up meanings than it is for me to argue, that this isn't a slippery slope - it's right on throwing my free time in the mound of chatGPT, and I won't do that.

Comment: @All - To avoid the arguments just being transferred from the (now locked) question into comments on this answer, it too has been locked - otherwise, from experience, locking the question will have no useful effect.